# bash script which runs fine gives read -p no coprocess under sh

Tags: bash, shell, android

This multi select menu works fine under bash, but when i try and it under sh on android it fails with the error "read -p no coprocess"

Any suggestions are welcome...

```
options=("AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD")

menu() {
    echo "Avaliable options:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    if [[ "$msg" ]]; then echo "$msg"; fi
}

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
    (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
    { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
    ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
    [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
done

printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
    [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling and reading, i think i solved it, at least it works perfectly now for me :)

sh likes the variable before the prompt:

```
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
```

becomes:

```
while menu && read num "$prompt" && [[ "$num" ]]; do
```

Full code follows

```
options=("AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD")

menu() {
    echo "Avaliable options:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    if [[ "$msg" ]]; then echo "$msg"; fi
}

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read num "$prompt" && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
    (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
    { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
    ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
    [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
done

printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
    [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
done
echo "$msg"
```